# gnuplot survival function

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to draw survival function using gnuplot's "cumulative" directive.
By survival function I mean 1-CDF. We can use "cumulative" to draw CDF as follows

```
plot 'datafile.dat' using <column with values>:(1./total number of values) smooth cumulative;
```

What I want to do is just multiply the y axis by -1 and offset by 1. i.e.

```
plot 'datafile.dat' using <column with values>:(1)-(1./total number of values) smooth cumulative;
```

But this does not work because accumulation is performed as the last step.
Any pointers ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a little bit confusing what you are actually trying to accomplish here.  I bet you can do it with inline functions, but I'm not 100% sure.  (I'll happily delete my answer if it is not helpful).

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to solve the this problem:

1. multiply the aggregate with -1
2. Re label the y axis to hide the actual labels:

i.e.

```
set ytics ("1" 0, "0.75" -0.25, "0.5" -0.5, "0.25" -0.75,"0" -1)
plot 'datafile.dat' using <column with values>:(-1./total number of values) smooth cumulative;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I think what you want to use is an *inline* function which was introduced in gnuplot 4.4 (?).   It works like this:

```
cumm_sum=0.0
nrec=0.0
CDF(x)=(nrec=nrec+1, cumm_sum=cumm_sum+x, 1.-cumm_sum/nrec)
plot 'datafile.dat' u (CDF($1)):2
```